# correct path for np.load function in python

Tags: python, numpy, path, load, structure

I have a small question which about the funcion of numpy load.

First I save a Matrix called matrix.npy to a Folder called No_Shadowing using np.save.
I have the following folder structure: scripts -> Plots -> NO_Shadowing
Inside the folder scripts I create a script in which I want to load the saved matrix.
I don't understand which path I should give np.load, so that it loads my file.
Do I need to give the path from scripts, e.g. something like np.load('Plots/No_Shadowing/matrix.np)? I tested all variants I can imagine, none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends...if the path is relative to your current folder you can use:

```
import os
np.load(os.getcwd() + "\\scripts\\Plots\\No_Shadowing\\matrix.np")
```

or...if scripts is at the root dir.

```
np.load('c:\\scripts\\Plots\\No_Shadowing\\matrix.np')
```